# Tab Navigation Grid view Item click not working

Tags: android, tabs, tabnavigator

[image]I created two tabs with tab Navigation. Each tab have grid view with custom adapter. My problem is Item click of grid view is working with one tab but in second tab item click not working. Can you guys suggest me why? Please

First Tab: here item click working :

```
public class MyPictureFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemLongClickListener{

    private final static String TAG="MyPictureFragment";
    private static SharedPreferences Prefs = null;
    private static String prefname = "galleryPrefs";
    private GridView gridview=null;
    List<PartnerImage_Model> list_images=new ArrayList<PartnerImage_Model>();
    TextView textviwe;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mypictureuploaded, container, false);
        gridview=(GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridView_pic);
        textviwe= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        gridview.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);




        return view;
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onClick click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return false;
    }


}
```

second Tab code:

```
public class MyVideoFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemLongClickListener{

    private final static String TAG="MyVideoFragment";
    private static SharedPreferences Prefs = null;
    private static String prefname = "galleryPrefs";
    private GridView gridview=null;
    List<PartnerVideo_Model> list_video=new ArrayList<PartnerVideo_Model>();
    TextView textviwe;
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myvideouploaded, container, false);
         gridview=(GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridView_video);
        gridview.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);


         return view;
}

    @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onClick click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return false;
        }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice: Return `true` from `onItemLongClick` method. i.e.

```
@Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onClick click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return true;
        }
```

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html) for android documentation

Comment: No any error, Just pressing the item click it is not showing toast or log